# Tricky limit of summation

Tags: limits

Find the limit as $n$ tends to infinity of

$$\frac{e^{1/n}}{n^2}+2\frac{e^{2/n}}{n^2}+3\frac{e^{3/n}}{n^2} + \ldots + n \frac{e}{n^2}$$

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: Is the last term correct?

Comment: @ajotatxe yes it is $n\frac{e^{n/n}}{n^2}=\frac{e}{n}$

Answer (score 10):

It's a Riemann sum that approaches
$$
\int_0^1 xe^x\,dx.
$$
The partition is $0,\ 1/n,\ 2/n,\ 3/n,\ \ldots,\ n/n$, so $\Delta x=1/n$ in every subinterval.

Note that $\displaystyle\int x\Big( e^x\,dx\Big) = \int x\,dv = xv-\int v\,dx$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

The sum  can be expressed on a closed form. Then, the asymptotic expansion leads to the limit equal to 1.

[image]